# Transfer DAO's from Myetherwallet to Kraken

Tags: tokens, dao, myetherwallet

I'm trying to transfer some DAO's from Myetherwallet.com to Kraken.
I've followed instructions to access my funds through Myetherwallet:
-Pasted "to" address (already active in Kraken), 
-Introduced amount (10% of my total amount), 
-Generated transaction, 
-Pressed "Send transaction" and "YEs I'm sure..." 
but system responds: "Account does not exist or account balance too low"

Seems sure that account exist
and for sure I'm sending a fraction of the total amount od DAO's in Myetherwallet account.

So, anybody knows why I'm not allowed to transfer DAO's

Answer (score 1):

You need ensure the account has sufficient GAS to pay for the transfer. Try sending over a small amount of Ether to the account (eg 0.01 ETH). That should be more than enough to cover the price of GAS required.