# How to transfer DAO from MyEtherWallet to Kraken? (DAOs transfer method)

Tags: wallets, the-dao, dao, exchanges, myetherwallet

Related:

- [Transfer DAO's from Myetherwallet to Kraken](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/transfer-daos-from-myetherwallet-to-kraken)
- [How to withdraw Ether from The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-to-withdraw-ether-from-the-dao)

MyEtherWallet screenshot:
[image]

The balance is low because all **Ether** was invested in **DAO**.

Here is the Kraken interface:
[image]

> use the DAOs transfer method (or transferWithoutReward) with your deposit address as destination to deposit tokens into your Kraken account

Is there a way to conduct **DAOs transfer method** directly from MyEtherWallet?

*(I only hope that I didn't accidentally published my private key alongside with screenshots)*

Comment: Same process, just use the DAO tab.

Comment: I tried the same thing but the tokens are not transfering... I just get debited a small amount of ETH for the fees...that's all...any ideas....

Comment: If you have voted on a proposal, your tokens are locked until the voting period is over. See if you have voted on an open proposal here: https://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO?a=<YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE>#votes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-tokens.
2. Enter your private key and unlock your wallet.
3. Enter your Kraken address and the number of The DAO tokens you want to transfer.
4. Ensure the "DAO" Radio button is selected.
5. Click Generate Transaction.

[image: mew token tab]

Comment: I confirm, it works for me. I missed (the obvious) ```The DAO``` tab...

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: tokens are owned by an address and there is only one way to move them. Go for it.** 
Both Kraken and MyEtherWallet have no choice than use the same process by moving DAO tokens. In fact, there is no other way to move a DAO token (which is a unit in a balance in a DAO token contract) than calling the contract in the Ethereum network, proving that you are in possession of the old address owning the tokens and telling the contract that there is a new address that should own the tokens. You have enough Ether on the account to buy the gas for the transaction.